# How to say "eat out", e.g. at a restaurant?

Tags: phrase-request

English has got an expression *to eat out*, meaning eating but not preparing the meal for yourself (i.e. restaurant, fast food, kebab etc.). What are ways to express the same in German?

Comment: https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/eat%20out

Comment: I suggested to edit the title, to avoid confusion with the slang term...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A standard phrase (see [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=korpus21&q=essen%20gehen)) here in Germany is

> essen gehen

(i. e. to go somewhere to eat as opposed to prepare the meal oneself).

Comment: Varianten sind "zum Essen ausgehen" und "zum Essen rausgehen".

Comment: @PaulFrost "zum Essen rausgehen" is not suitable. It means "to go outside (of where you are) to eat", there is no hint someone goes to a restaurant or other place. You could cook on your own and go outside to eat because the weather is fine. You can even only go out of a room to eat for a reason, not necessarily out of the house.

Comment: @puck It may in fact be confused with "draußen essen" oder "zum Essen nach draußen gehen". But it is not unusual to say "zum Essen rausgehen" in the context of the question. Beispiel. "[Also zum Essen rausgehen lohnt nicht](https://www.tripadvisor.de/ShowUserReviews-g651918-d1038131-r170808019-Felsentor-Hauenstein_Rhineland_Palatinate.html)".

Comment: The website you linked to indeed uses this phrase, but to me this is a slightly different situation. This is an unspoken comparison. They say *it doesn't pay to go out of the hotel to eat*, meaning you can stay in the hotel to eat - where "in" isn't "inside" because they mention the terrace right after ;-) It means *within the hotel's restaurant*. But to express you don't eat at home it would be odd to say "ich gehe zum essen raus" because primarily that says you go outside to eat. It's better to say "ich esse auswärts".

Answer (score 11):

It is

> auswärts essen

> Möchtest du heute daheim essen oder auswärts?
> Would you like to eat at home or out today?

The adverb *auswärts* has three meanings:

1. to the outside

> Versuchen Sie, Ihre Füße etwas weniger auswärts zu drehen wenn Sie laufen.
> Try to turn your feet a little less outwards when you run.

2. not at home, somewhere else

> Ines hat letzte Nacht auswärts geschlafen.
> Ines slept out last night.

3. in another town (mainly in sports)

> Der FC Unterhausen hat auswärts 1:0 gewonnen.
> FC Unterhausen won 1:0 away.

Comment: Though "auswärts essen" has a bit of an "official" ring to it. You might find it in the PR material of a restaurant trade association rather than in every day talk. For the latter, "essen gehen" as mentioned in another answer sounds more natural.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck: I think this is a question of personal opinion and maybe regional usage. I do hear any "official" ring when my wife says she wants "auswärts essen".